# Xamarin.Forms webview authenticate, navigate to new page (Shell) and need to re-auth again?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a webview in a Shell Xamarin.Forms app. I request a secure page and get forwarded to my company SSO (Single Sign On), I pass that and can see the secure content.

The webview:

```
<WebView x:Name="web1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000"/>
```

When I then navigate to a new Shell page from the main menu or by tapping an item in a listview (*think RSS Headline list, tap to read article*) which has an almost identical WebView tag on the xaml page, set the Source to a secure page on the page constructor or override OnAppearing, expecting the session/cookie to still be active I instead get forwarded to a login page again.

Is there any way that anyone knows I can ensure that all webviews in my app (iOS & Android) use the same session so the user only has to login once.

I've tried creating a the webview in the app.xaml.cs file and adding it to my pages using `Content.Children.Add(App.Web1)` which in my simple mind should mean I'm using the same webview on all pages and therefore the same session!? but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to set the session/cookie by creating a custom renderer of webview in native project. See these thread for more details: [Xamarin WebView Cookie to seamlessly authenticate user without re-entering credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051774/set-xamarin-webview-cookie-to-seamlessly-authenticate-user-without-re-entering-c) and [Setting Cookies in a WebView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41039/setting-cookies-in-a-webview).

Comment: Tried this. Before I remove the cookies in the new webview I've reviewed them and they are the auth cookies already there! (still doesn't work) - I then remove them, add my new ones from a successful call in the past, and still I get forwarded to the sign on service.

Answer (score 0):

Using cookieJs along with normal cookie insertion methods can solve the problem of setting cookies on the front-end side:

CookieJs:

```
!function(e){var n;if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var t=window.Cookies,o=window.Cookies=e();o.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,o}}}(function(){function e(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var o in t)n[o]=t[o]}return n}function n(e){return e.replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,decodeURIComponent)}return function t(o){function r(){}function i(n,t,i){if("undefined"!=typeof document){"number"==typeof(i=e({path:"/"},r.defaults,i)).expires&&(i.expires=new Date(1*new Date+864e5*i.expires)),i.expires=i.expires?i.expires.toUTCString():"";try{var c=JSON.stringify(t);/^[{[]/.test(c)&&(t=c)}catch(e){}t=o.write?o.write(t,n):encodeURIComponent(String(t)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),n=encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent).replace(/[()]/g,escape);var f="";for(var u in i)i[u]&&(f+="; "+u,!0!==i[u]&&(f+="="+i[u].split(";")[0]));return document.cookie=n+"="+t+f}}function c(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof document){for(var r={},i=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],c=0;c<i.length;c++){var f=i[c].split("="),u=f.slice(1).join("=");t||'"'!==u.charAt(0)||(u=u.slice(1,-1));try{var a=n(f[0]);if(u=(o.read||o)(u,a)||n(u),t)try{u=JSON.parse(u)}catch(e){}if(r[a]=u,e===a)break}catch(e){}}return e?r[e]:r}}return r.set=i,r.get=function(e){return c(e,!1)},r.getJSON=function(e){return c(e,!0)},r.remove=function(n,t){i(n,"",e(t,{expires:-1}))},r.defaults={},r.withConverter=t,r}(function(){})});
```

Sample:

iOS Renderer:

```
public class DefaultWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler, IWKNavigationDelegate
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";        
        const string cookieJs = "!function(e){var n;if(\"function\"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),\"object\"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var t=window.Cookies,o=window.Cookies=e();o.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,o}}}(function(){function e(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var o in t)n[o]=t[o]}return n}function n(e){return e.replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,decodeURIComponent)}return function t(o){function r(){}function i(n,t,i){if(\"undefined\"!=typeof document){\"number\"==typeof(i=e({path:\"/\"},r.defaults,i)).expires&&(i.expires=new Date(1*new Date+864e5*i.expires)),i.expires=i.expires?i.expires.toUTCString():\"\";try{var c=JSON.stringify(t);/^[\\{\\[]/.test(c)&&(t=c)}catch(e){}t=o.write?o.write(t,n):encodeURIComponent(String(t)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),n=encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent).replace(/[\\(\\)]/g,escape);var f=\"\";for(var u in i)i[u]&&(f+=\"; \"+u,!0!==i[u]&&(f+=\"=\"+i[u].split(\";\")[0]));return document.cookie=n+\"=\"+t+f}}function c(e,t){if(\"undefined\"!=typeof document){for(var r={},i=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(\"; \"):[],c=0;c<i.length;c++){var f=i[c].split(\"=\"),u=f.slice(1).join(\"=\");t||'\"'!==u.charAt(0)||(u=u.slice(1,-1));try{var a=n(f[0]);if(u=(o.read||o)(u,a)||n(u),t)try{u=JSON.parse(u)}catch(e){}if(r[a]=u,e===a)break}catch(e){}}return e?r[e]:r}}return r.set=i,r.get=function(e){return c(e,!1)},r.getJSON=function(e){return c(e,!0)},r.remove=function(n,t){i(n,\"\",e(t,{expires:-1}))},r.defaults={},r.withConverter=t,r}(function(){})});";
        WKUserContentController userController;
        public DefaultWebViewRenderer()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null && e.OldElement == null)
            {
                userController = new WKUserContentController();
                var cookieValue = string.Empty; //Whatever you want
                var jsScript = new WKUserScript(new NSString(cookieJs), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, false);
                var yourCookie = new WKUserScript(new NSString("Cookies.set('CookieKey','" + cookieValue + "',{expires : 30, domain : '.yourdomain.com' })"), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, false);                  
                userController.AddUserScript(jsScript);
                userController.AddUserScript(yourCookie);                    
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                userController.AddUserScript(script);
                userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);

                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
                userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Element.Source is UrlWebViewSource urlSource)
                {
                    var url = new NSUrl(urlSource.Url);
                    var storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
                    storage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
                    var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(url);
                    Control.LoadRequest(request);
                }
                else if (Element.Source is HtmlWebViewSource htmlSource)
                {
                    Control.LoadHtmlString(htmlSource.Html, null);
                }
            }
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            Element.JavascriptBridgeInvoked(message.Body.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Android Renderer:

```
public class DefaultWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";
    public DefaultWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null && e.NewElement is CustomWebView webView)
        {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewTestClient());
            Control.ClearSslPreferences();
            Control.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(false); 
            Control.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.NoCache;                
            Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
            cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
            cookieManager.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(Control, true);
            try
            {
                Control.SetDownloadListener(new DownloadListener());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            }
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
            if (webView.Source is UrlWebViewSource webSource)
            {
                Control.LoadUrl(webSource.Url);
            }
        }
    }

    private void InjectJS(string script)
    {
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("javascript: {0}", script));
        }
    }
}
public class WebViewTestClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
         var cookieJs = "!function(e){var n;if(\"function\"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),\"object\"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var t=window.Cookies,o=window.Cookies=e();o.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,o}}}(function(){function e(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var o in t)n[o]=t[o]}return n}function n(e){return e.replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,decodeURIComponent)}return function t(o){function r(){}function i(n,t,i){if(\"undefined\"!=typeof document){\"number\"==typeof(i=e({path:\"/\"},r.defaults,i)).expires&&(i.expires=new Date(1*new Date+864e5*i.expires)),i.expires=i.expires?i.expires.toUTCString():\"\";try{var c=JSON.stringify(t);/^[\\{\\[]/.test(c)&&(t=c)}catch(e){}t=o.write?o.write(t,n):encodeURIComponent(String(t)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),n=encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent).replace(/[\\(\\)]/g,escape);var f=\"\";for(var u in i)i[u]&&(f+=\"; \"+u,!0!==i[u]&&(f+=\"=\"+i[u].split(\";\")[0]));return document.cookie=n+\"=\"+t+f}}function c(e,t){if(\"undefined\"!=typeof document){for(var r={},i=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(\"; \"):[],c=0;c<i.length;c++){var f=i[c].split(\"=\"),u=f.slice(1).join(\"=\");t||'\"'!==u.charAt(0)||(u=u.slice(1,-1));try{var a=n(f[0]);if(u=(o.read||o)(u,a)||n(u),t)try{u=JSON.parse(u)}catch(e){}if(r[a]=u,e===a)break}catch(e){}}return e?r[e]:r}}return r.set=i,r.get=function(e){return c(e,!1)},r.getJSON=function(e){return c(e,!0)},r.remove=function(n,t){i(n,\"\",e(t,{expires:-1}))},r.defaults={},r.withConverter=t,r}(function(){})});";
        var cookieValue = string.Empty; //Whatever you want
        view.EvaluateJavascript(cookieJs, null);
        view.EvaluateJavascript("Cookies.set('CookieKey','" + cookieValue + "',{expires : 30, domain : '.yourdomain.com' })", null);
        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        view.ClearCache(true);
    }
    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.ClearCache(true);
    }
    public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
    {
        handler.Proceed();
        base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}
public class DownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Webkit.IDownloadListener
{
    public DownloadListener()
    {
    }
    public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) || !Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out _))
            return;
        try
        {
            if (HasPermissions())
            {
                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(contentUri);
                request.SetMimeType(mimetype);
                var cookies = Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);
                request.AddRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.AddRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.SetDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.SetTitle(Android.Webkit.URLUtil.GuessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.SetNotificationVisibility(Android.App.DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
                request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, ".pdf");
                Android.App.DownloadManager dm = (Android.App.DownloadManager)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.DownloadService);
                dm.Enqueue(request);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    private static bool HasPermissions()
    {
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            string[] WriteLocation =
            {
                Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
                Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
            };
            var perm = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
            if (perm != (int)Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.RequestPermissions(WriteLocation, 2);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
    private readonly WeakReference<DefaultWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;
    public JSBridge(DefaultWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<DefaultWebViewRenderer>(hybridRenderer);
    }
    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export("invokeAction")]
    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out DefaultWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer) && hybridRenderer != null && hybridRenderer.Element is CustomWebView webView)
        {
            webView.JavascriptBridgeInvoked(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't set set HttpOnly cookies on the front end though? Also I think this might be down to Xamarin.Forms 4.5 update which removes the WebViewRenderer and replaces with WKWebViewRenderer...worth investigating.